# Manipular evento com JQuery quando formulário e link são gerados automaticamente

Tags: jquery

JQuery não funciona quando o formulário ou um link é gerado automaticamente.  Exemplo abaixo:

Este exemplo funciona.

```
<a id='btnTreatInvite' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-check' href='#'>&nbsp; Aceitar</a>  

$("#btnTreatInvite").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('event works');       
});
```

Quando o mesmo link é gerado automaticamente não funciona.

```
var table ='<table id="tableInviteRqd">';
    table +='<thead>';
    table +='<tr>';
    table +='<th data-toggle="true">Nome</th>';
    table +='<th data-hide="phone,tablet"></th>';
    table +='</tr>';
    table +='</thead>';
    table +='<tbody>';

$.each(data, function(i, item){ 
    table +='<td>' + item.name + '</td>';
    table += "<td><a id='btnTreatInvite' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-check' href='teste.php'>&nbsp; Aceitar</a></td>";
 });                        
    table +='</tbody>';
    table +='</table>';
```

Comment: Este é o stackoverflow em Português. Traduza sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que estás a associar o evento a elementos que não existem no DOM quando o mesmo é lido pelo navegador.

Para resolver, deverás fazer uso de [delegação](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), anexando o evento a um elemento que existe na página na altura em que é carregada e delegando o mesmo para determinado elemento:

```
$("body").on("click", ".classeDosLinks", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('event works');
});
```

Em cima o evento anexado ao `body` e delegado para elementos com a classe de CSS `classeDosLinks`, muito embora deverás usar um *scope* mais curto, ou seja, anexar o evento num elemento mais próximo que o `body`, talvez uma `<div/>` que serve de *wrapper* ao conteúdo dinâmico.